# How can I see how much space I am using on my Dropbox for Business account?

Tags: dropbox

My University [signed up for a Dropbox for Business account](https://newsoffice.mit.edu/2014/ist-offers-dropbox-business-file-storage-sharing-mit-community-0821). I would like to know how much space I am using on this account. Looking at https://www.dropbox.com/account#work, I can see the space used by everybody as having access to this account.

[image]

How can I see how much space I am using on my Dropbox for Business account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found so far is to install the Dropbox client. During the installation the Dropbox client proposes to configure which folder to synchronize, it will then say how much space you use on your Dropbox for Business account:

[image]